# How to display nvarchar datatype image to SSRS Image control?

Tags: image, reporting-services

Actually I am new in SSRS(SQL Server Reporting Service). I have to display signature image in SSRS Image Control.The signature image is stored in nvarchar datatype.If you required in other information then ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Danish

Answer (score 1):

SSRS Image Control displays string image data fine, with no extra settings.

Just Drag an Image control in the Report and in `Image Properties` `General` tab,

choose `Select the image source:` as `Database`

[image]

and select the appropriate field in the `Use this field:` option. i.e the db field which holds the image data.

and select proper MIME in  `Use this MIME type:`. Though any of them should work for you.

Comment: Really appreciated! Actually i exactly do that and its not working. i donot know what is the reason.But i think so there is something worry with the field datatype.i already mentioned it is nvarchar.Is there any thing to convert that datatype.I also try each option of MIME type.

Comment: then probably your image data is wrong. you are not storing proper image data in string. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118840/how-to-convert-image-to-string-the-most-efficient-way) for converting image to string and saving in db.